# Error when running X apps with XWayland: "cannot open display: :0"

Tags: wayland, weston

I'm trying to run a simple X app under Weston using XWayland, but I get an error. I launch Weston as follows:

`$ weston-launch --modules=xwayland.so`

With the command-line argument as suggested [here](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/xserver.html) (cf. "weston.ini"). (I've also tried creating the `weston.ini` as instructed, and I got the same effect.) When I open the Wayland Terminal and run `$ echo $DISPLAY`, it returns with `:0`. But when I run a simple app like `/usr/bin/galculator`, I get the error `cannot open display: :0`. Any suggestions on how I might get galculator to launch? (That is, on how I might get an X client to connect with XWayland?)

It appears that Weston is trying to make an X server available since there is a display variable, just like was stated at the XWayland page. When I do the same experiment but I do `weston-launch` without the `modules` command-line argument, `echo $DISPLAY` returns nothing.

Note: I am using the `2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.zip` available [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads). I haven't done any installation of Weston or Wayland since they appear to be already installed on this image. Indeed, `/usr/lib/weston` has the `xwayland.so` module, along with other Weston-related code, and Weston otherwise launches just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Weston doesn't support `X` yet.

You can read more about it in [this Raspberry Pi forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=52699). Here is what [Wikipedia has to say about Weston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29):

> The [Raspberry Pi Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Foundation) are working in collaboration with
>   [Collabora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collabora) to improve performance and memory consumption, but do
>   not expect to be able to replace X11 as the default display server
>   until later in the year.

Basically, this is the whole reason Weston hasn't been set as the default yet for the Raspberry Pi.  Once `X` is supported, I presume that the shift will start to make Weston the default, while bugs are removed and features are added.  This should happen later this year, or early next year.

Comment: Thank you syb0rg for taking the time to respond. I understand that XWayland isn't in anything near a final state. Likewise, [this link] (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1319830#p1319830) indicates that XWayland can provide _some_ functionality. X clients are connecting. So I believe that the problem I'm having is due to a configuration issue, and not fundamental issues with XWayland itself. After all, it seems like an emulated X server would, at the very very least, be able to allow an X client to connect to it. Otherwise the devs wouldn't be able to develop against it. No?

Comment: @einnocent I couldn't find anything that said that Wayland had already been developed for the Raspberry Pi specific ARM chip.  That is why the developers had to "start over".